# How to mix to material with mix node

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have 2 different material (Ocean & Snow) from PBR material Addon. I want to mix both the nodes so that they combine each other smoothly. I have a node with green and white mix and same way i want combine both nodes to achieve a smooth result. Any suggestion or help how can mix both the Materials. Why there is a black edge line seen. Thanks

[image]

**Smooth Result** [image]

**Mix node** [image]

**2 different materials** [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a node setup is a group of nodes that you build, to get a virtual material for a single object. As i see in your images, there are 2 objects, a "landscape"/mountain and a plane. You need to do that material just to the mountain (maybe extend the mountain mesh, or joining the meshes). On your node setup, under "texture coordinate", try to use "object" instead of "generated". To control the transition, in the color ramp node, change the mode until you get want you like.

On your node setup, connect directly the mix shader to the material output. Delete the diffuse shader.

The ocean should be just a plane that cuts the landscape and you move on Z axis, up and down to where you want it.

[image]

For a 3 material setup, procede as the following image, where you replace the RGB nodes with the materials you built:

[image]

Comment: I think you did not get mean. I want the 2 nodes (snow and ocean) to be mix like the green and white.

Comment: And you did not read what I wrote. Your ocean and your mountain are different objects. A node setup is for 1 object.To fix the black line, you just need to pull the ocean on Z up a bit.

Comment: for mixing the materials (for a single object), you can to your snow, and to your ocean, copy all the nodes (except material output), and build a node setup like what you presented, but instead of RGB nodes, you put the other nodes

Comment: but as they are separated objects you won't see a difference. You may join them to a single object if you wish

Comment: I group the snow and ocean node and plug to mix rgb node & removed the green and white . Still did not get the result.

Comment: your ocean and your mountain are different objects

Comment: Forget the below mesh (ocean). To the mountain the below part 15% need to be ocean and the top part to be snow

Comment: please check the new image I added to the answer. There is only 1 object, with 3 materials (snow, grass, water) separated by Z value of the terrain

Comment: I tried different way and got the result. I group the nodes (snow and ocean) and connected with the mix shader. Thanks

Comment: final result https://imgur.com/gallery/6CpXREV

Comment: if you consider the answer correct, you should mark it correct